# partially mapping the result of a NamedNativeQuery to a class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.2

I have an `@Entity` class `Person`, that has multiple fields and I would like to map the result of several `@NamedNativeQuery`s to the `Person` class however, the queries I am running do not return values for every field in the `Person` class. When I try to run a query I get the following errors:

```
[error] o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid column name bar.
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

My class is set up similar to this:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getBirthdate",
        //Returns values for {idnumber, name, birthdate}
        query = "EXEC dbo.proc_get_birthdate :name",
        resultClass = Person.class
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getBar",
        //Returns values for {idnumber, name, bar}
        query = "EXEC dbo.proc_get_bar :name",
        resultClass = Person.class
    )
})
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idnumber")
    private int idNumber;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private String birthdate;
    @Column(name = "foo")
    private String foo;
    @Column(name = "bar")
    private String bar;

    //All appropriate getter and setter methods are implemented
}
```

I double checked and all the columns in the `Person` class do, in fact, exist in the table being queried.

My actual class is much larger and due to that and some security concerns, I do not want my queries to have to return **EVERY** field and am hoping that there is a simple way to just give them a value of `null` if a value isn't returned by the query. I tried to set each field to `null` in the declaration (example below) but that didn't work either.

```
@Column(name = "bar")
private String bar = null;
```

I would really rather not have to create a tailored class for every single query I need to run so if what I'm trying to do is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that the error is due to mapping. It look more like a JDBC error that you're trying to return a column that doesn't exist in the table. I'm almost positive I've done something similar where not all of the class variables are returned in the query.

Comment: The column isn't being referenced in the query that is throwing the error. and the column does exist in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you misunderstood the `@NamedNativeQuery` use. This annotation should be used with a SQL Query and not with a stored procedure. Looking at the exception `SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` it is possible to see that is a grammar exception, the query could not be parsed.

With JPA 2.1 you could use the annotation `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` that is the one with support to stored procedures.

Comment: the framework i'm using implements JPA 2.0 which is why I'm using `@NamedNativeQuery`.

Comment: But as I said NamedNativeQuery is used for Query and not Procedures.

Comment: there's no other way to call a stored proc in 2.0 (that i'm aware of) tho and it works with the entities that i only have one query attached to